# Freemarker hash for Struts2 @s.select tag's list property

Tags: struts2, freemarker

I'm using Freemarker as the templating engine for a Struts 2 application and having some problems trying to pass a Freemarker hash to the @s.select tag's list value.

Currently I'm trying something like this in my template:

```
<@s.select name="myDropdown" list={"1":"Foo", "2":"Bar", 3:"Baz"} />
```

The resulting HTML that's rendered is this:

```
<select name="myDropdown" id="myDropdown">
    <option value="freemarker.ext.beans.HashAdapter$1$1$1@2c9bebb">freemarker.ext.beans.HashAdapter$1$1$1@2c9bebb</option>
    <option value="freemarker.ext.beans.HashAdapter$1$1$1@16ca4a">freemarker.ext.beans.HashAdapter$1$1$1@16ca4a</option>
    <option value="freemarker.ext.beans.HashAdapter$1$1$1@173ee8">freemarker.ext.beans.HashAdapter$1$1$1@173ee8</option>
</select>
```

Based on the documentation it seems like this should work, but really the only examples are of using Freemarker lists.  Hashes are only mentioned as another option, but I haven't been able to find any code examples that use them.

Ultimately my question is, what Freemarker syntax should I use with the Struts 2 select tag in order to render the following HTML?

```
<select name="myDropdown" id="myDropdown">
    <option value="1">Foo</option>
    <option value="2">Bar</option>
    <option value="3">Baz</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the listKey and listValue properties of the select tag seems to do the trick.

The working code is now:

```
<@s.select name="myDropdown" list={"1":"Foo", "2":"Bar", 3:"Baz"} listKey="key" listValue="value" />
```

Seems like that should be taken care of automatically by the tag, but I was not able to get it to work without explicitly setting those two additional properties.